# Proving certain almost homogeneous function is linear

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

I have the following problem:

> Let $ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous function satisfying $ f(3x) = 3f(x) $ and differentiable at $ x = 0 $. We are asked to show $ f $ is linear.

If it were a general homogeneous function, I could show this, but now I can't. All I know is that $ f'(0) = f(1) $ and $ f(0) = 0 $. Can someone please show me the rest? Thanks.

Comment: try $$y=ax+b$$ and put this into your equation!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner : wouldn't this mean I'm assuming f to be linear already?

Comment: Yes this would it mean, and then show that a polynnomial of degree $$n\geq 2$$ is not a solution of your equation.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner what about all the other functions that aren't polynomials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction one can show that $f(x)=3^nf(\frac{x}{3^n})$. Now we put $h=\frac{x}{3^n}$ then $f(x)=x\frac{f(h)}{h}$. Since $f$ is differentiable a 0, $\frac{f(h)}{h}\longrightarrow f’(0):=a$ when $h\longrightarrow 0$. The claim follows.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming differentiability at $0$, we don't actually need continuity of $f$. Since $f(0)=0$, we have for all $x\ne 0$,
$$
f(x)=3f\left(\frac x 3\right)=\cdots=3^nf\left(\frac x {3^n}\right)=x\frac{f\left(\frac x {3^n}\right)-f(0)}{\frac x{3^n}}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}xf'(0),
$$ that is, $f(x)=cx$ for some $c\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Well you do need continuity for it to be differentiable. However you don't need differentiability. It just makes the argument quicker.

Comment: Well, what I meant was assuming differentiability, global continuity is not really required. And we indeed need differentiability; mere continuity does not imply that $f$ is linear.